# No daemons are running after formatting the namenode

Tags: hadoop

After I format Namenode in singlenode cluster, I am not able to see any any java process or hadoop daemnos running in my cluster..I have restarted the cluster many times. But it didn't work.

Comment: Post the configurations, which version of hadoop you are using? Add more details. Delete the name and data directory and then try.

Comment: I am using hadoop-2.3

Comment: shall i use this command to remove the name directory "hadoop fs -rm -r usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/hdfs/namenode"  & hadoop fs -rm -r ${HADOOP_HOME}/hdfs/datanode to delete the data directory??

Comment: No. I am telling about the local directory. Location that set in **dfs.name.dir** property and in **dfs.data.dir** property in **hdfs-site.xml** should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

After you format your nanenode.... Ur name node will get a new clusterid. But all others nodes have old cluster ID. This will make ur cluster unstable. I'd u have a backup of metadata restore using that.

Comment: So what I can do now?

Comment: i think you have lost everything now, you can try to start namenode in restore mode. Before that delete all the data in namenode data dir.

Answer (score 0):

When you format the namenode, the namenode storage gets cleared and a new cluster id will be generated. The cluster id should be same across the cluster. This cluster id will be present in the namenode as well as datanode file system. 
As a solution for your problem perform the following steps

1. Clear all the datanode directories (local directories where datanode stores data)
2. Format the namenode
3. Start the cluster

Since you already formatted the namenode, I am assuming you don't have any critical data.Because you will loose all the data with the namenode format.